# New Order Email Notification not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email

The website I am working on doesn't sends the orders notification email either to admin nor to the customers. But the admin and customers receive registration and reset password notification emails. I don't know why this is happening. I am facing this issue for the past 20 days.

Answer (score 7):

First go to **System > Configuration > Sales Emails** and make sure that **Enabled** is set to **Yes**.

After that look in **core_email_queue** table. If there are entries in the table and customers/admin are not getting any emails it means cron job is not running.

More details [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-responsive-email#cron).

Comment: Yes, there are entries. How to enable cron job?

Comment: Enabled is set to Yes at System > Configuration > Sales Emails -> Order. Signup emails are received but order notifications are not coming.

Comment: What i will do my table core_email_queue  is empty

Answer (score 2):

As of magento 1.9, emails are queued up and are sent via the cron job. If you haven't set this up, you can manually run it by pointing your browser to the file, e.g. `http://www.yoursite/cron.php` . After you run this, you should receive your emails

Answer (score 2):

In magento 1.9 all the emails are queued up and then waiting for cron job to implement...

Simple cron job for cpanel user is

```
php -q /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/public_html/cron.php
```

or use this

```
php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

As per my research try one of them.

Settings of time can be as per shared hosting or VPN or dedicated. Most shared hostings allows 5 minutes you can try with 20 minutes.

Imran Khalid

Answer (score 1):

Magento new order email allows notifications to be sent to administrator(s) when there are new orders placed

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-new-order-email.html

Comment: Does this is work

Comment: Excellent Working its free extension

Comment: Please share correct link if you have