# Order confirmation, add order comment, Order (send email), Send Order Email Copy To

Tags: email, confirmation

I have a weird problem. For some reason, all order related functions doesn't work.
Order confirmation doesn't get send
Add order comment and email doesn't send
Clicking on the send email in order doesn't send
And adding send order email copy to "my email address" doesn't send.

HOWEVER, invoice, shipment, newsletter email and all the functions above works perfect.

I don't understand?!

Answer (score 3):

Check the settings in `System > Configuration > Sales Emails` for both `Orders` and `Order Comments`, makes sure `Enabled` is set to `Yes`.

If it's already set to Yes then then the issue is probably somewhere in the code, possibly a third-party extension. Check your `var/log` and `var/report` folders.

**EDIT**

If you are on Magento 1.9.1.0 make sure cron job is running. Look in `core_email_queue` table. If there are entries in the table and customers/admin are not getting any emails it means cron job is not running.

More details [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-responsive-email#cron).

Comment: Everything is checked and still no fix. So I decided to install on another domain to test. This time with no template or extension. Simply a pure magneto 1.9.1. I created a product and made an order and does the same problem. Only invoice and all other emails EXCEPT the order emails. Btw I am with host gator. Is it possible that there is a problem with the magneto 1.9.1 that I got?

Comment: If you are on Magento 1.9.1.0 make sure cron job is running. See [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49935/new-order-email-notification-not-working/49978#49978) post.

Comment: But if cron is not working, how come all other email works?

Comment: Because invoice, shipment, credit memo, newsletter (subscribe confirmation only) and customer registration emails are sent directly. Only order and newsletter are queued and sent using cron job.