# Magento Transactional E-mails sent, except NEW ORDER e-mail

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, transactional-mail

I have read the following solutions, but all of these seems not to work for my case:

[New order email confirmation not being sent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent)

[Magento 1.9.2 not sending new order confirmation emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78587/magento-1-9-2-not-sending-new-order-confirmation-emails)

[New Order Email Notification not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49935/new-order-email-notification-not-working)

My problem is, all of my transactional e-mails are being sent out, EXCEPT, the NEW ORDER e-mail.

My cron is also working properly.

I have disabled all 3rd party modules as well, but the "new order" email is not being sent. All the rest of the e-mails like invoice, shipping, order updates, are being sent. The only problem is the new order e-mail.

I hope somebody here encountered the same problem.

Comment: What do you see in the database table "core_email_queue" ?

Answer (score 0):

If cron is running properly, you can check the following issues

- check the database tables **core_email_queue** and **core_email_queue_recipients** where data are inserted or not.
- if not check the log files if there is any error related to email. You can create separate log file to check the function **queueNewOrderEmail** is calling or not by placing the below code in it.

  ```
  Mage::log("this is executed by order no:- ".$this->getId().", null, 'email.log');
  ```